# Logfile viewer that is able to consecutively remove uninteresting loglines

Tags: logs, log-analysis

When doing an error analysis with a log file it often happens that I don't know in advance what I am interested in, but want to go the other way: I look at the logfile, and want to remove uninteresting logfile lines with common messages consecutively until only the interesting stuff is left. E.g. I first want to remove all messages containing "INFO", then all log messages containing a specific very common warning. In the rest there is a common error message which is uncritical, so I want to remove this as well. And so forth, until I get to the meat. Is there anything that supports this process? Common logfile viewers seem to only support highlighting stuff, which isn't too helpful if I don't know the problem in advance.

Preferably the process should work as follows: The logfile is displayed, I can scroll around, and when ever I identify a common pattern I can select it via mouse and hide everything that contains that pattern with one click.

Comment: Given that log files are usually ASCII you could look at editors that (1) [can handle large files](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/785/text-editor-or-reader-for-working-with-huge-files-in-windows) and (2) have good macro capabilities. You then e.g. write a macro "Remove all lines containing [selected text]" and execute that while investigating.

Comment: It would also help if you could mention what OS this tool should run on: Linux? Mac OS(X)? Windows? There might be solutions not available for all platforms.

Comment: @Izzy If there are solutions that run only on some platforms, I could adapt. So I'd rather make it general.

Comment: OK, understood. You might wish to include that with your question (you can always [edit] it) – something like "preferably for X, but other platforms are accepted as well". At SR, we prefer to focus :)

Comment: @hstoerr When you say remove, you mean you'd like to filter out lines containing a specific string? As per your example, you start with a full log file, then you filter out lines containing "INFO", then you filter out even more lines by adding another filtering string in a logical AND with the previous one, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/) log file viewer for Windows allows you to highlight lines matching regular expressions, which I use to dim out uninteresting lines that match the expression.

It also has a Filter view which has an Invert Match feature, allowing you to show all lines except ones which match certain expressions.

[image]