# Read-only large file viewer (> 10 GB), including gzipped file

Tags: windows, text-editor, hex-viewer

Note: I have already read [Best viewer for large text files (> 10GB)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/best-viewer-for-large-text-files-10gb) and [Text editor or reader for working with huge files in Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/785/text-editor-or-reader-for-working-with-huge-files-in-windows) but here the specific point is the compressed file support.

---

In order to view the content of > 10 GB files, I usually use "wxHexEditor" which is great (see screenshot below).

You can seek very fast anywhere in the file.

**I'm looking for a similar big file viewer, that can also view .gz gzipped files, without needing to decompress it into a temporary file.**

Note: This is technically possible *without decompressing to a temp file*, for example with Python, you can do:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('test.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(1024*1024*1024)  # go to offset 1 GB
    print(f.read(1024))     # display the next 1024 bytes
```

**Is there a big file viewer that can do this?**

[image]